# How to disable certain intents in custom Alexa skill?

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, alexa-interaction-model

```
...
CountryIntent{ ... };
CityIntent{ ... };
YesIntent{ ... };
FallBackIntent{ ... };
...
```

I'm building custom Alexa skill. User calls **CityIntent** from **CountryIntent**. But, if user accidentally says *YES*, he'll call **YesIntent** from **CountryIntent**; that will be incorrect logic. 
How to disable **YesIntent** so that user calls **FallBackIntent** when he accidentally says *YES*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't disable intents. By building intents you teach your skill to understand specific sentences/words spoken by human - and once taught, it's hard to forget.

What you can actually do is build a [state machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine) and keep the current state of your conversation in [`SessionAttribute`](https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/custom-skills/manage-skill-session-and-session-attributes.html). Then in each intent you have to check in which state the conversation is and act according to your logic - so in your case when you expect city and someone says "Yes", your skill should ask once again about the city and ignore the "yes" answer.

Answer (score 1):

Agree with @slawciu. The best way to handle yes/no responses is to keep track of the last intent in the [session attributes](https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/custom-skills/manage-skill-session-and-session-attributes.html)

In your case, you can enable validation on the city intent to accept only valid city names thereby eliminating need to handle an incorrect response.

Answer (score 1):

You can enable ANY handler you've coded to handle the YesIntent by adding it as a true condition in the `canHandle` for the handler and you can match it with session values to make it possible for different handlers to be used depending on the context.

Here's an example.

```js
let attributes = await handlerInput.attributesManager.getSessionAttributes();

    return ((Alexa.getRequestType(handlerInput.requestEnvelope) === 'IntentRequest'
      && Alexa.getIntentName(handlerInput.requestEnvelope) === 'CityIntent')
      || (Alexa.getRequestType(handlerInput.requestEnvelope) === 'IntentRequest' && 
         Alexa.getIntentName(handlerInput.requestEnvelope) === 'AMAZON.YesIntent' &&
         attributes.last === "City"));
```

So if they explicitly hit the CityIntent, or they hit it before (and you stored that in `attributes.last`) but answered "Yes," it gets triggered.

Using the FallbackIntent when you know they might answer "yes" is an anti-pattern. It's intended to be used when they say something you *don't* expect. You expect "yes," so proactively handle it.